# React Browser updates before data fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am building a centralized gaming application where players can view their stats and performance in different "modes". Each player has their own profile page, which displays some information about them, and then their stats for the respective mode. Modes vary in stats, and thus layout, so I have given each mode its own unique component. Below is the code for my Dashboard component which is supposed to show the stats for the respective mode. I am using a useMode custom hook that just returns the name of the mode from the URL query i.e /players/player1?mode=classic which returns "classic". When a mode is changed, I want the getStatsForMode function to run, fire a request to my api, and return the stats for that player, in that mode. To change the mode, I am using a select menu that changes the user's query params to the specific mode name, (using NextJS router). Using the mode name I loop through an array of objects with each object just containing the mode name and their ModeDashboard. Each ModeDashboard accepts the same number of props, just the structure of the props are different.

The issue that appears is when I am changing modes, the queryModeSlug is changing correctly and so is the ModeDashboard, but the actual stats are not being fetched from the API. It seems like the browser is rendering everything on the page before the stats can be fetched. This throws an error everytime since the structure of the stats objects for each mode are completely different, and im left with "property goals does not exist on x". I've tried making the ModeDashboard an actual state using useState, instead of just declaring it as a const, but that did not work either. Is this an issue with how I am conditionally rendering my components? I've also attempted to use a busy state by setting the busy state to true in the cleanup function for useEffect and setting busy to false after I have fetched the data but it seems the browser updates before the useEffect cleanup can run.

**Dashboard**

```
 const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardProps> = ({
  dashboardStatsInfo,
  playerModeInfo,
  player,
}) => {
  const { queryModeSlug } = useMode();
  const [busy, setBusy] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [dashBoardStats, setDashboardStats] =
    useState<DashboardStatsInfo | null>(dashboardStatsInfo);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("GET STATS FOR MODE");
    getStatsForMode(queryModeSlug);

async function getStatsForMode(mode: ModeSlugName) {
  const response = await fetch(`API_URL`, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      uuid: player._id,
    }),
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  const { stats }: { hasStats: boolean; stats: DashboardStatsInfo } = data;

  setDashboardStats(stats ?? null);
  console.log("SET BUSY FALSE");
  setBusy(false);
}

return () => {
  console.log("SET BUSY TRUE");
  setBusy(true);
};


 }, [player._id, queryModeSlug]);

  const ModeDashboard = getModeDashboard(queryModeSlug).dashboard;

  return (
    <>
      <section className="stats-dashboard-container">
        {dashBoardStats === null || busy ? (
          <section className="stats-dashboard stats-empty">
            <h2> No stats for this mode</h2>
          </section>
        ) : (
          <ModeDashboard
            dashboardStatsInfo={dashBoardStats}
            playerModeInfo={playerModeInfo}
            player={player}
            modeQueryName={queryModeSlug}
          />
        )}

      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: How does the `getStatsForMode(queryModeSlug)` looks inside?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, I have it defined in my useEffect

Comment: Of course it is, sorry, didn't see it

Comment: This code looks fine, there is probably something wrong with the other parts that you didn't show. You can try to make a minimal example on codesandbox.